# backup file locally in shell script

Tags: shell-script, postgresql

This is my crontab:

```
crontab -e
30 5 * * * sh /home/donato/Documents/pg_bak.sh
```

Every day at 5:30am I want to execute a shell script I created called pg_bak.sh.

This is the contents of the shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PG_USER=donato
DATABASE=mydb
SERVER=216.58.219.174
DIR="$HOME/pg_bak"
DATE=$(date +"%m_%d_%y")
FILE="$DATABASE_$DATE"
# pass @ .pgpass

PG_BAK_NOW () {
  pg_dump -h $SERVER -U $PG_USER $DATABASE -f $FILE.sql  
}

echo "Ready to dump to $FILE" >> "$HOME/pg_status" 

cd $DIR
if [ -f "$FILE" ];
then
  rm $FILE
  PG_BAK_NOW 
else
  PG_BAK_NOW
fi
```

I want to backup the sql file on my local machine at ~/pg_bak, NOT on the remote server. In other words, I do not want to backup the file on the remote server. Will the pg_dump command be running in the context of the computer I am running it from or from the remote server?

Comment: if postgresql-client-common is installed -yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use

```
pg_dump -h $SERVER -U $PG_USER $DATABASE > $FILE.sql
```

to output the result of the command to the local machine.  You might want to pipe it through gzip or similar, first, to obtain a smaller dump.

Since I'm already here, a couple of other suggestions:

```
30 5 * * * /home/donato/Documents/pg_bak.sh
```

You don't need to invoke `sh` to run your script, just give it the owner execution bit.

And the whole chunk of code in the script immediately after the echo can be changed to:

```
cd $DIR
rm $FILE 2>/dev/null
PG_BAK_NOW
```

In fact, since now you're invoking `pg_dump` only once, there's no need to wrap it in a function -- just call it directly.

Comment: Quick question. I want to name my file with the current date in it. That's why I used $FILE.sql. In your example, you have the static string mylocaldump.sql.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I wanted to make clear that the resulting dump file was local but in doing this I removed the dynamic filename. Answer corrected -- in fact you only have to use the stdout redirection `>` in lieu of the `-f` option.